# vim line count of current paragraph

Tags: vimscript, counting

How to count lines in current paragraph?

```
echo line("'}") - line("'{")
```

is near, but not correct, and not considering corner cases.

How to fix? or use another approach?

**== Edit ==**

I wanna count inner lines of current paragraph using vimscript, i.e., count given by `yip`.

since both marks `'{` and `'}` both point to empty line or line that only containing blank (space+Tab) if posssible.

The corner case is thus when above condition not match, that is, `'{` is first line and/or `'}` is last line of the graph.

**== Solution ==**

see [my answer below](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/14294/10254), -- a vimscript function that could be embeded inside of `statusline`.

Comment: What are some corner cases that you're facing? Like if the paragraph is a single line? (Then a minimum of 1 will fix it) Do you need to count wrapped lines?  Or, if not used in a Script, how about `set relativenumber`?

Comment: In my vim 8.2 (on windows) -- the `'{` and `'}` marks do not match lines that contain only spaces, and ONLY match fully blank lines.  I'm not sure if that changed in the last 4 years.

Answer (score 5):

You can <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> to select the current paragraph.

If you press <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>CTRL + G</kbd> you'll get

```
Selected 3 of 5 Lines; 8 of 12 Words; 101 of 291 Chars; 101 of 297 Bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not emphasize, as the tag indicates, I want a vimscript solution.

Never mind, I found a solution, and wrap it in a function.

```
func! LineCountCurrentParagraph()
    return line("'}") - line("'{") + ((match(getline("'{"),'^\s*$') == -1) + (match(getline("'}"),'^\s*$') == -1) -1)
endfunc
```

which is then used inside of my `statusline` settings.

```
set statusline+=%{LineCountCurrentParagraph()}
```